Wordpress tries to connect as 'username_here'@'localhost' to MYSQL because of wp-config-sample.php
I run WordPress on my server, and everything is working well.
However, 1-2 times a day, I get the following warning in my Syslog:
Dec 26 04:48:35 my_hostname mariadbd[895]: 2024-12-26  4:48:35 12606 [Warning] Access denied for user 'username_here'@'localhost' (using password: YES)

Now, I searched the entire server with SilverSearcher, and the only location where username_here is used on the entire server is within the wp-config-sample.php, which looks exactly like the original one here.
I modified the username there to username_here_example, and the following log looks like this, confirming that this file is the source.
Dec 26 21:24:13 my_hostname mariadbd[895]: 2024-12-26 21:24:13 19868 [Warning] Access denied for user 'username_here_example'@'localhost' (using password: YES)

However, from my understanding, WordPress should never use these credentials to connect, as this is only the default config. As far as I can tell, WordPress usually uses the credentials in wp-config.php to connect to the database, and the website works just fine, and the WordPress database looks okay, too.
Any hints for what could cause this behaviour?

First, I recommend executing a proper search as described by Oliver Dulac, as your situation might be different from mine.
In my case, it turned out that the warning aligned (by timestamp) with GET requests to said example config:
"GET /wp-config-sample.php HTTP/1.1"

Now, the wp-config-sample.php file includes the wp-settings.php at the very end (require_once ABSPATH . 'wp-settings.php';) which tests the DB connection (via require_wp_db(); if I understand correctly, but no guarantees) using the default credentials which obviously won't work and generate the syslog warning.
To get rid of the warnings, I simply denied any direct access to the file in the root .htaccess file of WordPress (e.g., /var/www/your_wordpress_dir/.htaccess):
<Files wp-config-sample.php>
order deny,allow
deny from all
</Files>

After this, trying to access the page should give a 403 Forbidden error instead of 500 and no database log warning will be written:
[27/Dec/2024:21:22:23 +1100] "GET /wp-config-sample.php HTTP/1.1" 403 4395 "-" "..."

Many .htaccess you can find, e.g., by wordpress.org or others, only explicitly block access to the wp-config.php as it includes the actual credentials. Access to wp-config-sample.php might be less critical, but blocking these requests does not do any harm, and reducing access where it is not needed is always good (and you get rid of the syslog warnings).

Try:
sudo grep -Er 'username_here|wp-config-sample\.php' / 2>/dev/null  
# I purposefully look in the whole system to also look mentions in log files, etc. 
# This will take a loooong time.
# you could restrict the search to /etc and whatever place wordpress was installed in, 
# but I recommand searching / to also cover other things (/var/adm, /var/log, /var/spool*, etc)

To see if some other file (a config file? a crontab? a script?) references that one to do some actions, instead of referencing the correct wp-config file ?
Another (unlikely but still) possibility: could someone be trying to hack their way into your box by somehow launching commands that use wp-condif-sample.php as credential source?

Great idea, the command is running. I did the same search for username_here before and there was no other result. I'll report what the search for the config file returns.  The potential of an attack is the reason why I'm investigating this. However, nothing else on the server indicates anything. Moreover, all admin pages (wp-admin) are behind an additional HTTP basic auth layer which has not seen any connection attemps. I don't really have any idea how they would be launching such commands.

add also a look for symlinks that could end up pointing to that wp-config-sample.php file? sudo find / 2>/dev/null | grep "wp-config" and see if any file is a symlink ... -> /path/to/wp-config-sample.php # and to be thorough, find /path/to/wp-config-sample.php -ls, note the first number (=that_inode), and then sudo find / -inum that_inode 2>/dev/null to see if any hard link points to it

@Erik : so? did it find something?

Sorry, I was away and only had phone access, so I wanted to write a proper response later. I did find something: In the apache2 access log (/var/log/apache2/access.log), I found a few GET requests: "GET /wp-config-sample.php HTTP/1.1". These align exactly with the above syslog entries. Turns out, the wp-config-sample.php calls wp-settings.php which tests the database connection. The .htaccess file does block access to the wp-config.php but did not include the wp-config-sample.php. I added it, and no further errors occurred since. I assume it was just a bot scanning the server.

Ah, and the other 2 commands didn't find anything new, i.e., neither hard nor symlinks to the file exist. Thanks a lot for your help!
